# I cannot print on Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I cant print on python. Currently using Python 3.6. Whenever i type

```
print("Hello World")
```

It gives me this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.
```

Any help? I am a newbie at Python

Comment: Do `del print` and then try again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Have you used any variable named `str` or `print` in your code?

Comment: Try restarting your Python Shell.

Comment: Try `globals()` to look at the current scope's global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assigned some string to the `print` name before you tried that line. You can reverse that using `del print`, or just restarting your interpreter.